# echo $array with declare key?

Tags: php, arrays

What am I doing wrong?

```php
echo '<pre>'; print_r($ar[2020]); echo '</pre>';
```

result:

```php
Array
(
    [2020] => Array
        (
            [2020-01-27] => Arg1
            [2020-01-07] => Arg2
        )
)
```

```php
echo $ar[2020][2020-01-27];
```

**unexpected**

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1992 in...

**expected**

> Arg2

Comment: I disagree with the close vote, this is not a typo, it was OP not quite understanding that the array key needs quoting, when it is a _string_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your array keys, like so:

```
echo $ar[2020]['2020-01-27'];
```

Otherwise, PHP will interpret that "key" as numbers, and is actually doing some maths, to give you that "1992", understand that `2020 - 01 - 27 = 1992`!  Which is a key that does not exist in your array.